# python change directory

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a small python program, which will be running on all nodes, I have 4 nodes
with names like pl-1,pl-2,pl-3 and pl-4 and each node will have a directory like

```
/home/backup/traffic-1, 
/home/backup/traffic-2,
/home/backup/traffic-3,
/home/backup/traffic-4
```

respectively.
Now I have a python script which will be running on all pl-'s, which will do os.chdir to
/home/backup/traffic-[?] and remove contents of traffic-[?]. 
Since the instance of the script is same in all pl-s, how can I change the directory to
/home/backup/traffic-[?] so that while executing script on pl-1 the chdir goes into 
/home/backup/traffic-1, pl-2 into traffic-2, etc.?

Comment: Paragraph breaks would help the readability of your question a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change directory, it's brittle. Use the full path to the file when opening it.

Comment: There is only one instance of the script, so chdir should happen according to pl-'s name, the instance of script running on pl-1 should be remove traffic-1 data, pl-2 should remove traffic-2,.....

Comment: @user1081026: No. Don't chdir.

Comment: Below one works if hostname has just one digit end, 
i need to split for one digit and also for more than one digit, 
like i need to split for eg pl-1 and also for pl-10. how to do it?

    from socket import gethostname
    postfix = gethostname().split('-')[1]
    dir = '/home/backup/traffic-'+postfix

Comment: @user1081026: That doesn't change the directory, it just calculates it. That's fine. Then you use that path + the filename to open the file. See also os.path.join(). http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join

Comment: @user1081026: Also, I answered your question. Do *not* change the directory. use the full path. That is the answer. If you have **further questions** then you should press the "Ask Question" button in the top right corner.

Answer (score 1):

```
from socket import gethostname
postfix = gethostname().split('-')[1]
dir = '/home/backup/traffic-'+postfix
```

Comment: In some case the postfix number can be more than 1 digit, how to handle this? Eg, for node number say 10, It should handle for both single digit and multidigit number postfix

Comment: Below one works if hostname has just one digit end, 
i need to split for one digit and also for more than one digit, 
like i need to split for eg pl-1 and also for pl-10. how to do it?

    from socket import gethostname
    postfix = gethostname().split('-')[1]
    dir = '/home/backup/traffic-'+postfix

Comment: I dont understand your question, what's your problem? Try to split string 'pl-10' and you get two vars list ['pl','10'].

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the node number as a parameter of your program to build the target path.

If the execution line of your script must be the same for all nodes, you can write the number in one file (like some sort of config file) and then read it from your script.

Comment: Then you can choose the second way, write a file to config each node.

Comment: Below one works if hostname has just one digit end, 
i need to split for one digit and also for more than one digit, 
like i need to split for eg pl-1 and also for pl-10. how to do it?

    from socket import gethostname
    postfix = gethostname().split('-')[1]
    dir = '/home/backup/traffic-'+postfix